# How to fix ImportError : DLL load failed for scipy.spatial module?

Tags: python, windows, dll, python-3.6, importerror

It's been a week I have been searching for an answer, but I have not found a way to solve my problem.

I'm running python 3.6 on Windows, and I have this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Alexis/folder/tag_activity.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
  File "C:\Users\Alexis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\__init__.py", line 101, in <module>
    from .qhull import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: Le module spécifié est introuvable.
```

Here is a few lines to give context :

```
# In tag_activity.py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
import boto3
import requests

# In scipy.spatial module
from .kdtree import *
from .ckdtree import *
from .qhull import *
from ._spherical_voronoi import SphericalVoronoi
from ._plotutils import *
```

I really don't understand why it doesn't works, because when I try to access .qhull.py file with CTRL+click on Pycharm, I can access the module.

I've tried to reinstall scipy with adequate .whl file (`scipy-1.3.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`) from Christoph Gohlke website, but it doesn't solve anything.

Edit : I can't install python 3.7, I'm using libraries that aren't supported, and the script will run on servers using python 3.6

Answer (score 0):

try installing through with the standard command line
`pip install scipy`

or clone on https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e1/9e/454b2dab5ee21f66ebf02ddbc63c5f074b21c44e66e1a509b38566cac9d9/scipy-1.3.1-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl

Comment: install python3.7.3

Comment: or `pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: try `pip uninstall numpy` and `pip install numpy==1.17.0`

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I can't use python 3.7 (I edited my post).

Comment: what version of windows do you use?

Comment: try to install on windows https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53587

Comment: I use Windows 10, version 1803, with x64 processor